# Identify different versions of people’s names as the same individual

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-matching

I have the following information *for the same individual* in column A of a spreadsheet:

```
ALAN K HURTZ
ALAN K HURTZ, ATTY
ALAN K. HURTZ
ALAN K. HURTZ, ATTY
ALAN K. HURTZ, ATTY.
ALAN HURTZ
ALAN HURTZ NDER
ALAN HURTZ ORPD
ALAN HURTZ, ATTY
ALAN HURTZ, ATTY.
ALAN HURTZ, ESQ
ALAN HURTZ, ESQ.
ALAN P. HURTZ, ATTY.
```

In another spreadsheet I have this row:

```
A           B         C         D       E        F

Hurtz       Alan      K.        ALIAS   91065    1451894
```

I need to be able to add to sheet1 column B this value: `1451894` (column F from sheet2)
for each record. I have not had any luck with VLOOKUP or MATCH.

Any suggestions on how I can compare these values?

Comment: how is allan p. hurtz the same as allan k. hurts?

Comment: what data cleaning techniques did you try? (e.g. for extracting "last_name first_name" format from sheet 1 column A?)

Comment: now we know that alan is a lawyer

Comment: This is not a trivial task in any application, especially in Excel. You could try `SEARCH` to check whether the terms in "another sheet" exist in any given data row, but you will have to decide whether that is sufficient to positively identify the target data. On that note, you have only provided the data you expect to match, not data that should not match. So even if you get a solution here that is specific to Mr. Hurtz, it might not be acceptable in your real-world data.

Comment: @deathApril - it is a typo - our data is full of them...I have tried combining first middle and last from sheet two into another cell and tried using the MATCH.  I have tried splitting the fullname from sheet 1 into first middle and last and tried using VLOOKUP.  I have tried making sheet 2 the source of a database query in order to use the LIKE function.  Additionally, this is a first pass that will be given to a human to verify and correct.  I am just trying to save some time doing as much as possible with non-human tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This challenge is not suitable for Excel, in part because `SEARCH` and `FIND` only work left to right and only locate the first instance. However, you can't be hoping to get a perfect result from any automated solution and may be prepared to accept a poor approximation with something relatively simple - ie it is your choice how much effort you spend on the coding as opposed to the human review.

To start with I suggest creating a Lookup table from your second sheet with first_name, initial, last_name and first_name, last_name both pointing to the values you have in ColumnF. In the first case you may want to concatenate something like " inc Initial" to your ColumnF value to indicate a closer match than without matching initial.

Then I'd suggest copying ColumnA of your first sheet into ColumnB and deleting ESQ from ColumnB (at least for surnames not starting ESQ!). In the US there are about 40,000 people whose surnames start "Esq" but it may be easier to deal with these as a separate issue than to forego the convenience of being able to 'ignore' Esquires.

The I'd suggest entering the following in ColumnsC:N respectively (assuming Row1 is a data label): `=FIND(" ",B2)` `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",B2)),0,FIND(",",B2))` `=LEN(B2)` `=LEFT(B2,C2)` `=IF(C2>0,MID(B2,C2+1,E2-C2+1),0)` `=LEFT(G2,1)` `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",G2)),0,FIND(" ",G2))` `=MID(G2,I2+1,E2-C2)` `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",J2)),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",J2)),0,FIND(".",J2)),FIND(",",J2))` `=IF(K2=0,J2,LEFT(J2,K2-1))` `=IF(I2>0,F2&H2&" "&L2,F2&L2)` `=VLOOKUP(M2,array,2,FALSE)` where 'array' is the Lookup table in Sheet2.

Out of your sample of 13 that should give you 'matches' for 8, with 5 of these including match of middle initial. If not good enough then just keep adding more formulae in columns on the right until you reach your trade-off point (for example, though your 13th example is one of the 5 above that do not match, it would do if in a separate column you did not concatenate the 'P' - with the fact that it matched in such other column a sign that it was not as close a match as the 8 others). And you could treat ATTY the same way as ESQ, though there are over 100,000 people with that surname in USA.

Alternatively you could offer a bounty or try freelancer.com where I'd expect you could find plenty of people happy for a small sum to provide code that would not only be much more selective but would probably give you a 'score' to indicate how likely any 'match' is.